How do i fix error Namespace not specified AGP 8.5.1
I'm encountering a "Namespace not specified" error while working on my Android project. I've confirmed that my Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) is updated to version 8.5.1, and I'm using Android Studio 2024.1.1.12 on Windows. Despite trying to update AGP through the updater assistant, it appears that I'm already running the latest version. Below is the content of my build.gradle.kts file for reference. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
This is my current code:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.exptracker"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    resourcePrefix("com.example.exptracker")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")

    // Room dependencies
    val room_version = "2.4.2"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")
}


Please [edit] and also provide your root gradle file and your settings gradle.

Specify the namespace in the android scope under the package by specify the package. Usually, you can find these under the AndroidManifest.xml
Example in the build.gradle(react-native-maps package)


    android{
             namespace "com.rnmaps.maps"
           }



Example in the AndroidManifest.xml(react-native-maps package)


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rnmaps.maps" >
</manifest>




Why do you use JavaScript code snippets for Gradle/Groovy and XML? The snippets only produce errors. Did you mean to use a [code block] instead? You should [edit] your answer and fix that.

Also, the question uses Kotlin for their gradle files, why do you use Groovy in your answer?
